# php and mysql multi dimensional value

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I want to make a little program which calculates the price on base of 2 input Values (Height and  Width)

please check this image.I want to deposit this table in Database

http://www.flickr.com/photos/115339538@N03/12116547823/

So how I can realize this?
For example :

**Input fields:**

```
 1. GX (width) = 920  
 2. GY(height) = 1150
```

so now search this program through database

```
 1. find table 4
 2. column GX
 3. column GY
 4. column price?
```

and `find the price: 174,72 €`

I'm a bit confused, what is the best way?

Thank you

Comment: Is the price a function of the two variables ? Do you want to store the entire table of data, or only the values of height and width, and then recalculate the price from these values ?

Comment: the price is not a function, I want only to get the price on base of height and width. I want to save the whole table (see attach pic) in database to get the right price

Comment: Please do not just link to some flickr image, but _describe_ your database structure in your question.

Comment: currently I have no database structure. Thats the question how to make the best/efficiency db-structure

Comment: I would suggest having a table of gx values and a table of gy values (each with an id), then a table of values linking the id of the gx value and the gy value. This would allow you to have gaps easily. Whatever you do, do not store things in a php serialised array!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE something (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  price FLOAT,
  GX_max INT,
  GY_max INT,
  GX_min INT,
  GY_min INT,
  page INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

SELECT price
FROM something
WHERE page = 4
  AND GX_max >= 920
  AND GY_max >= 1150
  AND GX_min <= 920
  AND GY_min <= 1150;
```